# javascript- how can i sort my array (numbers) increasingly

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
        function ordine(){
            var numeri=new Array();
            for(i=0; i<=5;i++){
            numeri[i]=prompt("inserisci un numero");
            }
            for(x=0; x<=5; x++){
                for(j=0; j<=5; j++){
                    if(numeri[j]>numeri[j++]){
                        tmp=numeri[j];
                        numeri[j]=numeri[j++];
                        numeri[j++]=tmp;
                    }

                }

            }
            document.write(numeri);
        }
    </script>
```

i wrote this code to sort the array increseangly but it doesnt work. someone can explain me why?

Comment: You're doing `j++` too many times.

Comment: what is the expected output

Comment: [1,5,6,1,2,3,4].sort()

Comment: Probably one of the first things to do is to convert the **strings** you're getting from `prompt` into numbers...

Comment: "Doesn't work" is little use to us. Help us to help you and please explain what problem you're experiencing.

Comment: You need to learn the difference between `j++` and `j + 1`. `j++` modifies `j`, which you only want to do in the `for()` header, not every time you access an element from the array.

Comment: You're also never using `x`, and you're accessing outside the array when `j == 5`.

Comment: Google "bubble sort" and you'll see how the algorithm should be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Use sort() function:

```
document.write(numeri.sort());
```

Entered in random order, you will get the output:

```
1,2,3,4,5,7
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: But the OP really has `["1", "2", "11", "33", "22"].sort()` so needs more than sortI)

Answer (score -1):

The problem is in the `if` statement

```
if(numeri[j]>numeri[j++]){
                    tmp=numeri[j];
                    numeri[j]=numeri[j++];
                    numeri[j++]=tmp;
                }
```

the `j++` means that in the next line the value of `j` will be `j+1`. So, everytime you're accessing `numeri[j++]` you are actually accessing a different value.

```
if(numeri[i]>numeri[j]){
    tmp=numeri[i];
    numeri[i]=numeri[j];
    numeri[j]=tmp;
}
```

should work just fine